# Migrate MS Access backend to cloud

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, cloud

I have built a CRM for my company using MS Access 2016, and we are looking to be able to use it remotely. I have currently split the database and have the back-end residing on our company server/shared drive. As I see it, we could put the back-end on SQL Server, but that would mean finding a way to host it. We recently moved to Google Apps for Work and I have been looking at the Google Cloud platform (e.g. [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/)), but I don't know if it will integrate nicely with MSSQL. There's also Sharepoint, but we are are having difficulty even finding it to buy on Microsoft.com, and are trying to move away from Microsoft Office products anyway.

What would be the most stable, cost-effective, and fastest way to allow our employees to use our Access DB remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to migrate the database into SQL Server as step one. Then step two host the database in Microsoft Azure using the SQL DB service.

You can find more details and pricing here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/

Be sure you check the single database pricing. Unless you want the elastic scaling and performance.

Comment: @JBird Just to follow up on this I've just found a free ebook from Microsoft on migrating SQL Server databases to Azure: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2016/05/11/free-ebook-microsoft-azure-essentials-migrating-sql-server-databases-to-azure/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the cost part, but the fastest and most stable (IMHO) would be to use Remote Desktop. Either to a user's workstation or to a server set up for it.

Comment: Actually, we had used that in the past but our terminal server died, one reason we are looking to move to the cloud and away from our own servers. Good idea though!

Answer (score 0):

We have migrated our backend to SQL Server from MS Access for obvious reasons. Our users access the front end off a VPS Hosted in the cloud. Connection string ODBC. It is robust and fast.

we are currently using a VPS. Looks cheaper and easy to access ;
https://clients.databasemart.com/aff.php?aff=275